# R iteratively join new columns to an existing table within a looping structure

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Below is a simplified version of a problem that involves transforming multiple input tables and joining the transformed output into a single table.

Three input tables are processed and summarized, yielding three output tables with identical `x` columns. `x` can thus be used as index variable to combine the tables with `left_join`.

`out_all` is the desired final output table, with index column `x` and summary columns `d`, `e`, and `f`.

This code achieves the desired output, but it's not efficient for handling a large set of input tables.

What I hope to achieve, perhaps using `purr::map` functions or a loop
structure, is to iteratively join the new summary columns to the current version of the output table. Rather than pausing the workflow to save out the latest output, I want to feed that output back into the beginning of loop so that it forms the LHS of the next version of itself, with a new summary column added on the RHS.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
library(tidyverse)
in1 <- tribble(
~x, ~a, 
1, 1, 
1, 2, 
1, 3, 
2, 4, 
3, 5 
)

in2 <- tribble(
~x, ~b, 
1, 1, 
2, 2, 
2, 3, 
2, 4, 
3, 5
)

in3 <- tribble(
~x, ~c, 
1, 1, 
2, 2, 
3, 3, 
3, 4, 
3, 5
)

out1 <- in1 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(d = mean(a))

out2 <- in2 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(e = mean(b))

out12 <- left_join(out1, out2, by = 'x')

out3 <- in3 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(f = mean(c))

out_all <- left_join(out12, out3, by = 'x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going back to your first comment, if your original input is a single wide table, why not `gather` the columns of interest and use `dplyr` to `group_by` and `summarise` them in a few steps? Rather than creating various interim tables if those are not necessary for the desired output?

```r
df <- data.frame(id=1:5,matrix(runif(n=26*5),ncol=26))

df %>% gather(k,v,-id) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(m=mean(v))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id     m
  <int> <dbl>
1     1 0.522
2     2 0.596
3     3 0.535
4     4 0.548
5     5 0.605
```

Comment: Thanks kstew, your suggestion led me to a more elegant solution for the full-scale problem. I realized that I needed to re-think my basic approach to the problem, which was to split the large table into numerous interim tables, process and summarize them separately via an iterative looping structure, and then glue them back together into the desired final output table. Using the `dplyr` verbs (`gather` and `spread`) allows one to segregate "sub-tables" within the structure of the large input table, thereby avoiding creation of interim data objects.

Comment: In this specific example, I found that the key to making the solution run was to use `group_by` to impose a hierarchical grouping structure based on two grouping variables.

Answer (score 1):

We get all the dataset objects into a `list`, use `map` to do the group by `mean` in the `list` and then `reduce` to a single dataste

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- mget(ls(pattern = "^in\\d+$")) %>%
          map(~ .x %>%
                 group_by(x)  %>% 
                 summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)) %>% 
          reduce(left_join)
```

---

Also, if we want to name the columns differently

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^in\\d+$")) %>% 
   map2(., c("d", "e", "f"), ~ 
        .x %>%
             group_by(x)  %>%
             summarise(!! .y := mean(!! rlang::sym(names(.)[2])))) %>% 
   reduce(left_join)
```

Comment: Thanks to akrun and @Joris for your suggestions. To add another layer of complexity, in the larger-scale problem, the input tables do not exist as separate data frames, as in my simplified example. There is a single wide input table, and the code extracts columns from that table to create interim tables, which are then processed, summarized and output separately. Thus, the opportunity to build a list of 'input' tables actually exists at the end of the pipeline, not at the beginning as in akrun's solution.

Comment: What would be useful would be to build that list of table recursively within `map`, such that each successive table created by the `map` iterations is dumped into the list, and the tables in that list are combined into a single final output table using `reduce(left_join)`. I hope that makes sense, and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For a larger number of input tables it might be more efficient to first combine the tables and then summarize values instead of first summarizing values and then (recursively) combining the tables. Here is a small demonstration with 26 input tables (which are already simplified to a single list of tibbles):

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

## data
in_dfs <- map(LETTERS, function(var) {
          tibble(x = sample(1:3, 5, replace = TRUE), !!var := 1:5)
        }) %>%
    setNames(paste0("in", seq_along(LETTERS)))

## first combine then summarize
out_tidyverse1 <- function(input) 
      do.call(bind_rows, input) %>%
      group_by(x) %>%
      summarize_all(~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))

## first summarize then combine
out_tidyverse2 <- function(input)
  map(input, ~ .x %>%
              group_by(x)  %>% 
              summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)) %>% 
      reduce(left_join)         

microbenchmark(out_tidyverse1(in_dfs), out_tidyverse2(in_dfs))

#> Unit: microseconds
#>                    expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq
#>  out_tidyverse1(in_dfs)   891.425  1052.342  1356.81  1186.545  1345.594
#>  out_tidyverse2(in_dfs) 20482.967 23807.713 26453.08 26144.013 28163.417
#>        max neval cld
#>   6790.026   100  a 
#>  36884.574   100   b
```

NB: this would probably be quite a bit more efficient with data.table using e.g. data.table's `rbindlist`